# insert into sqlite database table a row of values( list format) with the Columns also as a list

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to (per loop) insert in a database a row with around 700 measurement values. These values correspond to 700 measurement points (i.e. columns of the table Partnr1).  On the next row the next measurement file with its 700 measurement points needs to be inserted and so on.

my idea was
`cur.execute("INSERT INTO Partnr1 [COLNew] VALUES [COLvalue]")`
but this gives error:

> near "[COLNew]": syntax error

```
COLNew and COLvalue are lists in format
COLValue= [0.15, 0.21, 0.17, 0.22, -0.13, -0.16, etc]
COLNew=['ID', 'Description', 'Profil-Welle 52         ', 'Profil-Welle 53         ', 'Profil-Welle 54         ','Etc']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the SQL string first:

```py
numCols = len(COLNew)
numVals = len(COLvalue)

command = f"INSERT INTO Partnr1({'?,'*(numCols-1)}?) VALUES({'?,'*(numValues-1)}?);"
```

If there were 5 columns, command now looks like

```
'INSERT INTO Partnr1(?,?,?,?,?) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);'
```

By building the string this way, you can still use sqlite parameters.

You can then execute the command using

```
cursor.execute(command, COLNew + COLvalues)
```

Comment: Michael do I need to write: command=f"INSERT or command="INSERT (so did you make a typo with "f"INSERT) since the first gives error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    command = f"INSERT INTO Partnr1({'?,'*numCols-1}?) VALUES({'?,'*numValues-1}?);"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' with numCols=5 etc

Comment: I've edited my response. It was an order of operations error. The f is supposed to be there.

Comment: Mark the question as answered if this was the solution you were looking for.

Comment: where can I mark it? Likely a stupid questions since there must be a switch somewhere :)